# identifying the adjusted font size of a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

One of my labels is auto resizing to fit the text. How do I find out what the new dynamic size is? I want to match another label to this adjusted size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not native method to get the font size, but you can calculate the font size by using NSString's method [sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aminFontSize%3aactualFontSize%3aforWidth%3alineBreakMode%3a)